# Rust example in Rust Book: for loop over a range

Tags: rust

In the Rust Book there is an interesting example about an audio encoder: [Comparing Performance: Loops vs. Iterators](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-04-performance.html)

```rust
let buffer: &mut [i32];
let coefficients: [i64; 12];
let qlp_shift: i16;

for i in 12..buffer.len() {
    let prediction = coefficients.iter()
        .zip(&buffer[i - 12..i])
        .map(|(&c, &s)| c * s as i64)
        .sum::<i64>() >> qlp_shift;
    let delta = buffer[i];
    buffer[i] = prediction as i32 + delta;
}
```

1. I cant get what is iterating this for loop. In my mind, `12..buffer.len()` would iterate from the 13th byte of the buffer to the end of the buffer. Which doesn't makes much sense.
2. Also, when zipping, it is pairing the current item in coefficients —`coefficients.iter()`— and pairing with `buffer[i  - 12..i]`, which again makes no sense, as I don't know how can you take the index `i` and substranct a range like `12..i`.

Any help will be welcome!

Comment: As you guessed, you can't subtract a range from an integer. `buffer[i - 12..i]` should be understood as `buffer[(i - 12)..i]`

Comment: Interesting. Weird code, but makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop starts at `12`, thereby skipping the first 12 elements in the buffer:

```
for i in 12..buffer.len() {
```

As pointed out in the comments, `buffer[i - 12..i]` is actually interpreted by the Rust parser as `buffer[(i - 12)..i]`. So, later in the algorithm it refers to the preceding 12 elements:

```
.zip(&buffer[i - 12..i])
```

This is creating a sliding window of 12 elements, starting 12 elements before the current index, and then zipping them with the fixed array of 12 coefficients.

Comment: Thanks. I run the code step by step and now I get it… Also I was thinking that zip accepted an item, but it actually requires a list